# Is it possible for text/font to overlap input field?

Tags: text, z-index, overlap, input-field

I am wondering if it is possible to make the font/text inside of an input field overlap the input field itself.  I'd like to know if this is possible without doing something like creating two input fields with one overlapping the other and one having a hidden field box.

For instance, say you have a font that looks like handwriting and you want the descenders of lowercase letters (the bottom parts of "p" "y" "g" for instance) to hang below the field box rather than get cut off by it - similar to how handwriting extends below the baseline when writing on lined paper.

I've done extensive searching with little luck, so even if someone knows of a better search term than "text overlapping input-box" and similar such strings, that in iteself would be a tremendous help.

The thing is, I don't know of a CSS selector that just focuses on the text inside the input-box or I would try to increase the z-index of the text so that it would be on a layer above the box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried setting a background image on the input element?  Your background image could be the line.

i.e.

```
input {
    background: url(path/to/image.png) repeat-x;
}
```

**EDIT:**

I've had a quick play with this and have got something up and running here: http://jsfiddle.net/qUc9Y/

I've wrapped the input in another element (fieldset.input-wrapper) and moved your CSS transitions to this new element.  I've pushed the input down relatively 10px so it overhangs the shadow created by the container.  I've set the background of the input to transparent so the box shadows on the .input-wrapper are visible through it.

Finally, I've added some quick jQuery so that when the input is hovered, the css transitions are applied to the new .input-wrapper container (i.e. the input's parent).  You should be able to do the same for focus/blur.

I hope this helps.

**EDIT 2:**

The focus state should now work too, see http://jsfiddle.net/yZ3uw/14/ .

Comment: Hi,  thanks for the note.  I did consider using something like another image or some sort of backgdound, but I currently have an "active" input field, meaning that there is some execution of some fading CSS on the textfield itself (see: ournewlife.com/005/login.php).  The thing is, if I use a static image and layer the text over it or a static background I lose the hover and focus effects.  I would like to maintain the hover and focus effects of the CSS and still be able to have the font overlap the input box, if this is possible.

Comment: I've updated my answer with something I hope will meet the requirement of being able to keep your CSS transitions.  http://jsfiddle.net/qUc9Y/

Comment: Awesome, Chris.  Thank you for taking the time to put this together.  The only thing that is not operational is the focus, when I click on the box and type the color does not turn blue nor stay the color it is while in focus.  

I updated it with some more js (jsfiddle.net/yZ3uw/) that I thought would bring it through, but it still doesn't work.  I'm not entirely sure why, as it seems clearly indicated that on focus it should be blue.

Comment: No problem.  I've updated your version ( http://jsfiddle.net/yZ3uw/14/ ) to handle the focusing: The only issue was that hover() takes two functions (one executed on hover, the other on un-hover), but focus() only takes one.  It was just a case of moving the code that removes the 'input-wrapper-focus' class to a blur() handler.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Wow Chris, you're awesome.  Thank you so much for your kind help and knowledge on this!  I'm sure another user will come by, see this answer, and feel equally as grateful.  Thank you!  It's beautiful.

Comment: No problem at all, my pleasure :)

Comment: I think I see, so you needed to add a remove class to the focus so that there was an event after focus was removed?

Comment: It was basically down to the syntax of the jQuery: http://api.jquery.com/hover/ takes two functions (hover in and hover out), whereas http://api.jquery.com/focus/ only takes one function and relies on the "unfocus" behaviour to be defined in http://api.jquery.com/blur/ .